# Transparent canvas and transparent ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I have a renderer:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: false,
  alpha: true
})
```

And a ShaderMaterial:

```
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: { ... },
  transparent: true,
  blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
  vertexShader: renderVert,
  fragmentShader: renderFrag
})
```

And i have a fragment shader (simplified here):

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.0), 0.2);
}
```

But the alpha is not taken into account and the shader renders all colours fully opaque. Also with another blending mode still doesn't work as expected. Why?

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work as expected with one of the built in materials?

Comment: Solved via https://discourse.threejs.org/t/transparent-canvas-and-transparent-shadermaterial/3012/2?u=mugen87

Comment: Actually everything works as expected. It was a bug in my data that didn't show any change in the alpha value. Another example here where opacity is animated in the fragment shader (on a transparent canvas): https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6444/